# How to access git branch name from pipeline job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins Pipeline job which is configured to checkout a git repo and a specific local branch.

*How can i get the name of the local branch in my Jenkinsfile?*

I tried to load the git [jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) env properties but had no luck.

```
node {
  checkout scm
  echo "1 "+ env.GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH
  echo "2 "+ env.GIT_BRANCH
}
```

Both values are "null"

Answer (score 25):

I found that I can capture the return value from `checkout scm` and use that to get the branch name (and other values)

```
  def scmVars

  node('api-sample-build') {
    stage('Clone source code') {
        scmVars = checkout scm
        // scmVars contains the following values
        // GIT_BRANCH=origin/mybranch
        // GIT_COMMIT=fc8279a107ebaf806f2e310fce15a7a54238eb71
        // GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT=6f2e319a1fc82707ebaf800fce15a7a54238eb71
        // GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT=310fce159a1fc82707ebaf806f2ea7a54238eb71
        // GIT_URL=https://stash.someworkplace.com/scm/poc/api-sample.git
    }
    stage('test scope') {
      echo scmVars.GIT_BRANCH
    }
  }
```

By defining the variable outside the node it is available in stages after the checkout.

Answer (score 4):

I'm now using the sh call to get the branch name. This requires at least version 2.4 of the Pipeline Nodes and Processes Plugin.

```
def branchName = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD').trim()
echo branchName
```

Comment: I've tried the same thing but I'm getting HEAD instead of the branch name... any ideas? I've tried other ways as git branch | grep \* | cut ' ' -f but everything seems to return None or HEAD

Comment: @JavierPR You may be in a detached head state which won't work with this command. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059336 may help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scm` attributes to get the list of branches configured for your `scm` :

```
// List of all configured branches
def allBranches = scm.branches

// Only the first configured branch name
def gitBranch = scm.branches[0].name
```

Comment: org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM getBranches

Comment: @RicardoStuven You need to authorize that method signature in the scripts console.