# how to get repo name in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using Jenkins Scripted Pipeline that uses Groovy style scripting, and created a Jenkinsfile to describe the pipeline. I need to create the workspace with the folder name same as git repo name, and then checkout the code in the workspace folder. 
My question is, before doing the `checkout scm`, is there a way to know the git repo name or the git repo url?

Comment: Just a quick clarification, by Jenkins scripted pipeline you mean the Jenkinsfile coded in Jenkins pipeline definition or Jenkinsfile from the SCM?

Comment: There's the `scm` variable, which might have some info on that. That you need to create the workspace folder feels a bit odd to me.

Comment: @manish-joshi - I have the Jenkinsfile saved in the repo.

Comment: @StephenKing, I need the workspace folder in a specific order, because Go (golang) has specific convention that I need to follow inorder for the dependencies to work properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get scm url in build script for jenkins multibranch workflow project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38254968/how-to-get-scm-url-in-build-script-for-jenkins-multibranch-workflow-project)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
String determineRepoName() {
    return scm.getUserRemoteConfigs()[0].getUrl().tokenize('/')[3].split("\\.")[0]
}
```

This relatively ugly code is what I use to get the repoName. The key is that the URL of the repo is stored in:

> scm.getUserRemoteConfigs()[0].getUrl()

from there you need to do some string ops to get what you want.

---

Update:

```
String determineRepoName() {
    return scm.getUserRemoteConfigs()[0].getUrl().tokenize('/').last().split("\\.")[0]
}
```

This works also for repositories with a deeper hierarchy (https://domain/project/subproject/repo or ssh git repo which does not contain the two // at the start.

Comment: i got the this error `org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM getUserRemoteConfigs`

Comment: i used the hint from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38255364/2018909 to approve the script exception and was able to get the repo name. thanks @herm

Comment: I just did `.tokenize('/.')[-2]` which seems to get the same result more concisely.

Comment: you might want to use `String determineRepoName() {
    return scm.getUserRemoteConfigs()[0].getUrl().tokenize('/').last().split("\\.git")[0]
}` in case your repository name includes dots

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a silly answer, but isn't it possible using the environment Jenkins environment variable `env.BITBUCKET_REPOSITORY`?

Comment: If you mean that exact variable, no, because jenkins is not the same as bitbucket pipelines

Answer (score 0):

If your Jenkins server uses [Git Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/), you could use `GIT_URL` env variable to shorten your code. It support most Git Server (e.g. Bitbucket, Github, GitLab, Gitea, Tuleap)

```
GIT_URL.tokenize('/.')[-2]
```

PS: Crediting [Ben Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45684941/how-to-get-repo-name-in-jenkins-pipeline#comment86581088_45690925) for his suggestion on the tokenizer tips below.