# jenkins pipeline get repository url variable under pipeline script from scm

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using Jenkins file that located in my git repository.
I have configured new job using the pipeline script from SCM that point to my `jenkinsfile`. I'm trying to use in my Jenkins file pipeline script the git module in order to pull my data from my git repo without configure pre-static variable and just to use the variable of the repository URL under pipeline script from SCM that already was configured in my job .
There is a way to get somehow the variable **Repository URL**
from this plugin without using parameters in my Jenkins pipeline script.

I have already tried the environment variable `GIT_URL` and other stuff that related to git from [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project) but this didn't work.

[image: pipeline script from scm]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get scm url in build script for jenkins multibranch workflow project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38254968/how-to-get-scm-url-in-build-script-for-jenkins-multibranch-workflow-project)

Answer (score 26):

You can find all information about scm in `scm` variable (instance of [GitSCM](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/git/hudson/plugins/git/GitSCM.html) if you are using git).
You can get repository URL this way

```
def repositoryUrl = scm.userRemoteConfigs[0].url
```

But if you just want to checkout that repository you can simply invoke  `checkout scm` without needing to specify anything else. See [checkout step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/#code-checkout-code-general-scm)

Comment: I'm getting the error 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException' but if I have to approved the methods this is working .. I'm still trying to find another way without approve nothing before

Comment: @dsaydon I guess it is impossible without approving. Why it's a problem for you? BTW consider using just `checkout scm`.

Comment: Thank you for you help @vitalii-vitrenko . I found another way (not the best one) that did the trick . I just posted it

Comment: link is broken - believe it's this now: https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/git/hudson/plugins/git/GitSCM.html

Answer (score 3):

from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38254968/how-to-get-scm-url-in-build-script-for-jenkins-multibranch-workflow-project) I found a way that you can use the **checkout scm** to get the git repo url like this:

```
checkout scm
def url = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git config remote.origin.url').trim()
```

but **checkout scm** will pull the code and I want to avoid from that.

So I found another way (not the pretty one):

```
node('master'){

  try{
        GIT_REPO_URL = null
        command = "grep -oP '(?<=url>)[^<]+' /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/config.xml"
        GIT_REPO_URL = sh(returnStdout: true, script: command).trim();
        echo "Detected Git Repo URL: ${GIT_REPO_URL}"  
    }
    catch(err){
        throw err
        error "Colud not find any Git repository for the job ${JOB_NAME}"
  }

}
```

this is did the trick for me.

Comment: I find "/var/lib/jenkins" in your proposal rather scary.  Cannot you use the environ var JENKINS_HOME for that?

Comment: no, because in my solution you need the ```config.xml``` of the relevant job. buy why scary?

Comment: Using a hard-coded path for jenkins would break your code in case Jenkins is moved to some other location. And using a variable costs nothing.

Comment: @RaúlSalinas-Monteagudo you right! , this is just an example of implementation. you can use the Jenkins magics as much as you want

Answer (score 2):

Probably not directly a solution for your particular case, as you're working with git.

But for those still working with SVN using the [`SubversionSCM`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/subversion-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/scm/SubversionSCM.java), the repository URL can be obtained using

```
def repositoryUrl = scm.locations[0].remote
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the best solution is like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66375372/3796356) answer.
An example using declarative pipeline:

```
pipeline {
  agent any;
  stages  {
    stage('test'){
      steps {
        script {
          def s = checkout scm;
          if      (s.GIT_URL != null) print s.GIT_URL
          else if (s.SVN_URL != null) print s.SVN_URL
          else print s
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note - this does a full checkout. If that is not desirable, I would try to handle that in checkout parameters ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57869185/3796356))